# record encode play and save a wav file

Tags: c#, audio, rtp

Can someone give an example of how to record, play, save and also encode a .wav file in a pcm file (u-law encode for ex). I would like to create a rtp stream. THX

Answer (score 1):

[NAudio](http://naudio.codeplex.com) can be used to record audio, convert it to u-law and save it to a WAV file. The included NAudioDemo application demonstrates how to perform all three tasks.

For creating an RTP stream, you could try [RTP.NET](http://www.streamcoders.com/products/rtpnet.html)